# Java ActiveMq nonBlockingRedelivery

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am using `ActiveMQ` version 5.7.x,

I am having one `ActiveMQ` queue to which the listener listens.

Queue has a `ConnectionFactory` whose `redeliveryPolicy` is set to 3, `intialRedeliveryDelay` set to 5000.

Queue have some good messages and bad messages. While listening to such queue, when bad messages come, they are tried 3 times with the wait time of 5000 millis, but then the good messages are blocked for that much time span.

What I want is, during the wait time of 5000 millis for each retry, the processing of good messages should continue and should not wait for bad message processing.

For this I tried 1 attribute of `connectionFactory`, i.e. `nonBlockingRedelivery` set to true.

But `nonBlockingRedelivery` is not working.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can always have a retransmission queue for failing messages.

That is, receive messages from a main queue (no redelivery) and if you get an exception, put the message on a redelivery queue.

Let your application listen on both queues and do the same logic to both messages. It should simply be two message listeners invoking the same method. One with redelivery and one without, but with slightly different error handling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. got the answer. will try this and let you know.

Comment: But do you have any idea why nonblockingredelivery is not working for me?

Comment: No clue. Never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the description of that attribute in ActiveMQConnectionFactory,
It says what I exactly what I wanted..

"When true a MessageConsumer will not stop Message delivery before re-delivering Messages from a rolled back transaction. This implies that message order will not be preserved and also will result in the TransactedIndividualAck option to be enabled"

But same is not working..!!!

Can you please look into it please?

Comment: Make sure your Consumer is using the right ConnectionFactory